# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, laravel

I was try about CRUD with Eloquent but there is an error when I run my program

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pegawai.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `pegawai` where `pegawai`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

I just see my database is no problem but this happen when I want to run my program.
And I attach my controller

```
    public function pegawai_edit($id)
        {
            $pegawai = Pegawai::find($id);
            return view('pegawai_edit', ['pegawai' => $pegawai]);
        }
```

and this is my **web.php**

```
Route::get('/pegawai/pegawai_edit/{id}', 'PegawaiController@pegawai_edit');
```

This is my `pegawai` table :

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| pegawai_id | pegawai_nama | pegawai_jabatan | pegawai_umur | pegawai_alamat | created_at          | updated_at          |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 | Lucas        | NULL            |            1 | Jakarta        | 2021-09-29 09:07:09 | 2021-09-29 09:07:09 |
|          2 | Test         | NULL            |            2 | TEST           | 2021-09-29 09:07:26 | 2021-09-29 09:07:26 |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm using **laravel 8.6** and **mysql** is my database

Comment: According to the error, your pegawai table has no id column.  What does your pegawai table look like?

Comment: hi @ewong I add my table and have id on my table, also pegawai_id is primarykey

Comment: then the column name is ```pegawai_id``` not ```id```.

Comment: @ewong yes I'm using `pegawai_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, eloquent model use the field `id` as the primary key. Since you use `pegawai_id` instead, you need to set it in your model

```
class Pegawai extends Model
{
    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'pegawai_id';
}
```

once set, you can use all the methods eloquent provide without specificly telling it to use `pegawai_id` each time

```
public function pegawai_edit($id)
{
    $pegawai = Pegawai::find($id);
    return view('pegawai_edit', ['pegawai' => $pegawai]);
}
```

Comment: @OMR that is not an issue, since his call landed on the right table already, (the error is column not found not table not found) either it's already set or the table name in the question is not precise.

Comment: @OMR yes I have on my Models

Answer (score 1):

As you don't respect the Laravel standard, i.e. use `id` as the name for your `id` **column**, try like this :

```
public function pegawai_edit($id)
        {
            $pegawai = Pegawai::where('pegawai_id', $id)->first();
            return view('pegawai_edit', ['pegawai' => $pegawai]);
        }
```

Or modify just your `Pegawai` model, adding :

```
protected $primaryKey = 'pegawai_id';
```

Comment: it's better to set the primary key attribute of the model than patch every call/relation/....